How to Remove TimeStamp column from grafana Table Visualisation
enter image description hereI'm using Prometheus and monitoring it through Grafana. However, whenever I write a PromQL query and check it in table visualization, it always shows me a timestamp column which I don't want. Instead, I want the data to be shown for the time when I hit the query. Can anyone help me write a query that shows three columns: uri, status, and count?
Currently, I'm trying to use the following query:
sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count) by (uri, status)
But the resulting table includes a timestamp column which I'd like to remove. How can I modify this query to achieve the desired result?

Your query is correct (at least for described goal). To get what you want: change query type to Instant, and format to Table (all in options under query in editor). If you also want to hide column time completely, use Transformation Organize fields.
